# Error in generating password hash by werkzeug in python

Tags: python, werkzeug

I try to generate a password hash by generate_password_hash in werkzeug. But it seems not working.

```
>>> from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash  
>>> generate_password_hash('foobar')  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/l0o0/Workspace/flask/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/security.py", line 230, in generate_password_hash
    h, actual_method = _hash_internal(method, salt, password)
  File "/home/l0o0/Workspace/flask/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/security.py", line 192, in _hash_internal
    hashfunc=hash_func)
  File "/home/l0o0/Workspace/flask/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/security.py", line 65, in pbkdf2_hex
    return to_native(codecs.encode(rv, 'hex_codec'))
  File "/home/l0o0/Workspace/flask/env/lib/python2.7/encodings/__init__.py", line 120, in search_function
    entry = getregentry()
  File "/home/l0o0/Workspace/flask/env/lib/python2.7/encodings/hex_codec.py", line 79, in getregentry
    _is_text_encoding=False,
TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument '_is_text_encoding'
```

werkzeug version is Werkzeug-0.11.11 and was installed by pip. 
Hope someone could help.

ADDED: I hava tried to the same command in another server, it seems ok.
And I install this module by`sudo apt-get install python-werkzeug`, without virtualenv, it works fine.

Comment: I can't reproduce this with Python 2.7.12 and Werkzeug 0.11.11.

Comment: Do you perhaps have a `codecs.py` file shadowing the built-in? What does `import codecs; print(codecs)` produce (in the same location as your failing `generate_password_hash()` call).

Comment: I downloaded the latest Werkzeug (your version 0.11.11) and I can't reproduce either. However, by looking at the error, the problem seems to be in `hex_codec.py` in the `encodings` package? Is it possible that you have a newer (or older) version than the required by Werkzeug? (the setup.py of werkzeug might have some little bug?) Just guessing here...

Comment: @BorrajaX: note that that module import `codecs` and it is the `codecs.CodecInfo()` class that is not matching, which is why I ask about the output of the `codecs` import.

Comment: What puzzled me is that it still seems to be calling the built-in `hex_codec.py` instead of a _"shadower"_ `codecs.py`... ? I mean... I'm sure you (THE @MartijnPieters **:-)** ) understand this way way better than I do... I'm just getting stuff from browsing a couple of pages on GitHub Is just that now I'm curious myself...I found that the latest (in master) version of the hex_codec is indeed, passing that argument (https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/encodings/hex_codec.py#L54), yet the one I have in my laptop (Python2.7) doesn't? Baaah... I don't know **:-(**

Comment: @Martijn Pieters, after `import codecs; print codecs`, the message is :`<module 'codecs' from '/home/l0o0/Workspace/flask/env/lib/python2.7/codecs.pyc'>`.  the same path .

Comment: @l0o0: it sounds as if your virtualenv is out of sync; you only have *part* of [this changeset](https://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/cf6e782a7f94) for Python 2.7.11. I'd re-build the virtualenv.